# Different background color for each row in Google Sheets API BatchUpdate

Tags: go, google-sheets-api, background-color

I'm using the google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4 Golang package and can successfully update a Google Sheet using the API. However, I want to set the background color of a row if it meets a specific criteria. I'm finding that I cannot set the background color of one row different from the rest and I don't know why. Here is a code snippet

```
func (bs *BudgetSheet) populateCells() []*sheets.RowData {
    rows := []*sheets.RowData{}
    bgGreen := &sheets.Color{
        Alpha: 1,
        Blue:  0,
        Red:   0,
        Green: 1,
    }
    bgWhite := &sheets.Color{
        Alpha: 1,
        Blue:  1,
        Red:   1,
        Green: 1,
    }

    for _, csvRow := range bs.CSV {
        if csvRow.Name == "Credit Card Payment" {
            continue
        }

        cells := []*sheets.CellData{}
        row := &sheets.RowData{}

        cells = append(cells, mkNumberCell(4, centerAlign))
        cells = append(cells, mkStringCell(csvRow.Source, centerAlign))
        cells = append(cells, mkDateCell(csvRow.Date))
        cells = append(cells, mkStringCell(csvRow.Name, leftAlign))

        if csvRow.Source == "-" {
            if csvRow.Amount < 0 {
                cells = append(cells, mkNumberCell(-1*csvRow.Amount, dollarsCell))
                cells = append(cells, mkStringCell("", leftAlign))
            } else {
                cells = append(cells, mkStringCell("", leftAlign))
                cells = append(cells, mkNumberCell(csvRow.Amount, dollarsCell))
            }
            cells = append(cells, mkStringCell("", leftAlign))
        } else {
            cells = append(cells, mkStringCell("", leftAlign))
            cells = append(cells, mkStringCell("", leftAlign))
            cells = append(cells, mkNumberCell(-1*csvRow.Amount, dollarsCell))
        }

        if csvRow.Name == "Salary" {
            for i := range cells {
                cells[i].UserEnteredFormat.BackgroundColor = bgGreen
            }
        } else {
            for i := range cells {
                cells[i].UserEnteredFormat.BackgroundColor = bgWhite
            }
        }

        row.Values = cells
        rows = append(rows, row)

        emptyCells := []*sheets.CellData{}
        // cells = append(cells, mkStringCell("", centerAlign))
        emptyRow := &sheets.RowData{
            Values: emptyCells,
        }
        rows = append(rows, emptyRow)
    }
    return rows
}


func (bs *BudgetSheet) updateRows() {
    requests := []*sheets.Request{}
    rows := bs.populateCells()

    gc := &sheets.GridCoordinate{
        SheetId:     bs.ID,
        RowIndex:    bs.FirstRowToUpdate,
        ColumnIndex: 0,
    }
    updateCellsRequest := sheets.UpdateCellsRequest{
        Fields: "*",
        Rows:   rows,
        Start:  gc,
    }

    request := sheets.Request{
        UpdateCells: &updateCellsRequest,
    }
    requests = append(requests, &request)

    // create the batch request
    batchUpdateRequest := sheets.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest{
        Requests: requests,
    }

    // execute the request
    _, err := bs.Service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(bs.SpreadsheetID, &batchUpdateRequest).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not perform update action: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

The lines in question are

```
        if csvRow.Name == "Salary" {
            for i := range cells {
                cells[i].UserEnteredFormat.BackgroundColor = bgGreen
            }
        } else {
            for i := range cells {
                cells[i].UserEnteredFormat.BackgroundColor = bgWhite
            }
        }
```

My input results in one row meeting the criteria above an successfully sets the background color of all cells in that row to green. However, when I view the Google Sheet, all rows have a background color of white. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there @RobCallahan! I have been studying your example, but I can't replicate this behaviour. To better study this situation, could you please share a Sheet replica?

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron! Nice of you to try this out. This is my financial budget spreadsheet so I don't want to share it as is. I'll have to pare it down and share it. I'll need some time. Interestingly, I've been able to change the colors of other cells in a row so I must be doing something wrong. Just can't see it yet. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron, so just to be clear, are you able to update rows with different background colors using the BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest() method from google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the problem though I'm not exactly sure why. I'm pretty sure that the problem was using

```
cells[i].UserEnteredFormat.BackgroundColor = bgGreen
```

instead of defining the cells outright as in

```
func formatCell(align, colorName string, bordersOn bool) *sheets.CellFormat {
    return &sheets.CellFormat{
        HorizontalAlignment: strings.ToUpper(align),
        TextFormat:          font(),
        BackgroundColor:     color(colorName),
        Borders:             borders(bordersOn),
    }
}
```

In any case, the program works perfectly now and I'm perfectly happy. FWIW, the purpose of the program is the read the CSV transactions files downloaded from my checking and credit card institutions and update my register spreadsheet. While it doesn't save me a great deal of time each weekend, it was lots of fun to write. And a shout out to @Jacques-GuzelHeron for his attempt to help.